# iOS Enterprise App: Distribute Over the air : Untrusted Enterprise Developer

Tags: ios, xcode, download, enterprise-distribution, ios-enterprise

I have uploaded my .ipa and manifest.plist to my server (say : https: // www.xxxxxxx . xom/app/). And I created a install page in that server.

In that install html page I have the  hyper link to download my app

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http s: // xxxxxxx.com/ios/manifest.plist">
Download My  iOS App
</a>
```

If I try to install the app through this install page, the app get downloaded and installed. When I tap the app, it shows **"untrusted Enterprise developer".** And also I cant able to see **"Profile and device management"** in the setting app

Kindly help me how can i get rid of this **"Untrusted Enterprise Developer"**

**Note: 
I have already installed different certificate in my phone. Thats why It is not showing for my phone. But it is working in other iPhones**

Comment: it's named `Profile` I think, check for that one in `General`

Comment: I have already installed different certificate in my phone. Thats why It is not showing for my phone. But it is working in other iPhones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general settings of your iphone you could see Device management. Move into the section and trust your enterprise developer account.

Answer (score 2):

Here is proper document from Apple - [Install custom enterprise apps on iOS](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204460)

**Installing and Trusting an Enterprise App**

When you first open an enterprise app you've manually installed, you see a notification that the developer of the app isn't trusted on your device. You can dismiss this message but you can't open the app.

After dismissing this message you can establish trust for this app developer.

> (Tap) Settings ▶ General ▶ Profiles or Profiles & Device Management.

You then see a a profile for the developer under the "Enterprise App" heading.

Tap the profile to establish trust for this developer.

You're then prompted to confirm your choice. Once you trust this profile, you can manually install other apps from the same developer and open them immediately. This developer remains trusted until you use the Delete App button to remove all apps from the developer.

[image]