# Is there any way to add testing device UDID to free provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, provisioning

I don't have paid developer account and want to test my ios app on a team member's iPhone which is not registered to my provisioning profile. Is there any way to register a new device without deploying from the code directly.

Comment: This may help you -https://stackoverflow.com/a/47651180/5638630. It's an answer for enterprise profile but even the similar procedure works for unpaid developer profile also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Now you can not add `UDID` of a device in Free developer account, since a free account has no access to the `Certificates`, `Identifiers`, and `Profiles` in the developers portal.

But you can install the app by connecting (multiple, I guess upto three) device(s) with your Xcode.

Comment: Device is on the remote location...! So I can't install through my Xcode

Comment: Then there is no way using free provisioning to add udid.

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution for this... May not be a proper solution... Still if it can help..,
If you connect your device to mac and refresh your free provisioning profile in xcode with selecting connected device for running, in xcode that will automatically register your device to your provisioning profile. And you can access one provisioning profile on multiple mac by using same apple id and bundle identifier.

Note: you can register maximum 5 devices to a **free provisioning profile**.

Answer (score 0):

Free apple developer account dose not allow for create any development or distribution certificate and it is also not allow to add any UDID until enroll (99$ per year).

You can refer to this link:

[Adding UDID of testers with free developer account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932098/adding-udid-of-testers-with-free-developer-account)